# php server doesn't seem to execute code, although server is running

Tags: php

I haven't worked in a very long time with php so this question may be a very noob one.

I've installed apache server 2.0.65, and although when i call the localhost, my page in htdocs gets executed, only the html code appears in the view. The php code appears in the source view as html would, thus leading me to believe that it doesn't get interpreted.

My code is the from w3school:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

<?php
 echo "My first PHP script!";
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

what am i not doing ok?

Comment: Make sure the file extension is `php`.  Other than that the second question would be have you installed PHP?

Comment: What's the filename of the file which this code contains?

Comment: Use [`PHP` The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/), **not** [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You did not [install PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php)
- You did not configure PHP to run your file (by default it will process files with a `.php` extensions)
- You aren't actually visiting `http://localhost/foo.php` in your browser

Answer (score 2):

Apache would just run HTML, CSS. In order to make PHP work, you must install PHP, and set environment variable on your local machine, so that all files with .php extension would be run by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Filename must have a `.php` file extension.

PHP must be installed and running - if you can open a terminal and type `php -v` or use top to see if php is running.

If you are running on your local computer try installing WAMP or something similar.